# How to place SKSpriteNode in front of CAShapeLayer?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cashapelayer

I want to display a SKSpriteNode in front of a CAShapeLayer and this is the code that I am using :

```
import SpriteKit
import GameplayKit
import UIKit

class GameScene: SKScene {

    let progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        let circle = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.size.width, height: self.size.height))
        view.addSubview(circle)
        view.sendSubview(toBack: circle)

        progressLayer.frame = view.bounds
        progressLayer.path = progressPath.cgPath

        progressLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.green.cgColor
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 20.0

        let animation2 = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeEnd")
        animation2.fromValue = 0.0
        animation2.toValue = 1.0
        animation2.duration = 1
        animation2.timingFunction = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseOut)

        progressLayer.add(animation2, forKey: "drawLineAnimation")

        circle.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)

        var popup = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "popupWorking.png")
        popup.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5)
        popup.position = CGPoint(x: self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2)
        popup.size = CGSize(width: 400, height: 200)
        popup.zPosition = 10
        self.addChild(popup)
    }
}
```

But when I run the code, the CAShapeLayer appears in front of the SKSpriteNode, how do I make the SKSpriteNode appear in front of the CAShapeLayer?

Comment: Why you are using a CAShapeLayer in spritekit?

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to change your view hierarchy at the view controller level. By default the view controller's view is an `SKView`. If you want to place a different `UIView` behind your `SKView`, you will need to adjust the view hierarchy.

Modify the view controller's view to be a `UIView` instead of an `SKView`. Then, add your shape layer's view as a subview to this main view. After that, add your `SKView` as a subview of the main view.

Your new view hierarchy should look like this:

```
View Controller
    – view (UIView)
        - circle view (UIView with your CAShapeLayer as a sublayer)
        - spritekit view (SKView)
```

---

While it is possible to combine `UIKit` and `SpriteKit` in this way, it may be easier to stay within the `SpriteKit` world and recreate the circle animation using `SKSpriteNode`s instead of a `CAShapeLayer`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a playground that shows one way of doing it. I followed suggestion by @nathan .

Yellow line is drawn using SKShapeNode. The red shadow needs to be animated behind it and hence uses CAShapeLayer. (Note: I needed to mix the two as animating shadow path would be much more complicated in pure Sprite)

```
import SpriteKit
import PlaygroundSupport

private func invert(_ path: CGMutablePath)  -> CGPath {
    var rotation = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.0, y: -1.0);
    return path.copy(using: &rotation)!;
}

let bounds = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 400, height: 200)
let uiview = UIView(frame: bounds)
let pathview = UIView(frame: bounds)
let skview = SKView(frame: bounds)

PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = uiview


// Define the path
let path: CGMutablePath = CGMutablePath();
path.move(to: CGPoint(x:0, y:0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x:200, y:100))


// Use CAShapeLayer to draw the red line
var pathLayer: CAShapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
pathLayer.position = CGPoint(x: uiview.bounds.minX, y: uiview.bounds.minY + 200)
pathLayer.path = invert(path)
pathLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
pathLayer.fillColor = nil
pathLayer.lineWidth = 10.0
pathLayer.lineJoin = kCALineJoinBevel
pathLayer.lineCap = kCALineCapRound
pathLayer.zPosition = 3;
let strokeAnimation = CABasicAnimation(keyPath: "strokeAnimation")
strokeAnimation.duration = 2;
strokeAnimation.fromValue = 0;
pathview.layer.addSublayer(pathLayer);
pathLayer.add(strokeAnimation, forKey: "strokePath");

uiview.addSubview(pathview)

//Use SKShapeNode to draw the yellow line
let pathShape: SKShapeNode = SKShapeNode(path: path);
pathShape.strokeColor = .white;
pathShape.lineWidth = 2.0;
pathShape.zPosition = 20;

// Create SK Scene
let scene = SKScene(size: CGSize(width: 400, height: 200))
scene.scaleMode = SKSceneScaleMode.aspectFill
scene.size = skview.bounds.size
scene.addChild(pathShape);
scene.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear;
skview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear


skview.presentScene(scene);
uiview.insertSubview(skview, aboveSubview: pathview)
```